# Email URL reverts to text on refresh of webpage

Tags: html, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, richtext, hcl-notes

I have a Domino form that has a computed RTF that pulls text from a field using an @DbLookup. The text contains an email address enclosed in `<a </a>` brackets. When the page loads, the email address appears as expected. When a user clicks a search button that runs an agent to refresh a subsequent field, it replaces the email address with the exact text including the `<a </a>`.

The text (marked as Pass-Thru HTML in the field) is:
`Below are the groups that you have authority to administer. Please select one. If you have other groups that you would like to administer online, please email <a href="mailto: EmailAddress@Organization.org.">EmailAddress@Organization.org</a>.`

The code in the RTF to pull it is:
`@DbLookup("Notes":"NoCache";@DbName;"vwContentForms";"OtherReporting";@ThisName)`

When the page first loads, it displays properly.
`Below are the groups that you have authority to administer. Please select one. If you have other groups that you would like to administer online, please email EMailAddress@Organization.org.` with the email address marked as a link.

After pressing a search button on the form that refreshes the page, it replaces the text `email EMailAddress@Organization.org` with `<a href="mailto: EMailAddress@Organization.org.">email EmailAddress@Organization.org</a>.`

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Show us your code and any attempts that you have tried to make it work :-)

Comment: Forms can have RTFs, but Pages can't.  Please clarify. Also clarify what you mean by "when it refreshes". Is the user clicking the browser's refresh button? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Midway down in the [documentation for @DbLookup](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/11.0.1/basic/H_DBLOOKUP_NOTES_DATABASES.html), it says

> When you use a fieldName to perform a lookup, the value returned is the value that is actually stored in the field; it may be different from what displays in the view. Domino® can retrieve data from any field in any document displayed in the specified view, but if the field isn't displayed as a view column, Domino® must search the entire document to find the field, which may result in a slower lookup. **You cannot retrieve data from a rich text field using @DbLookup.**

This might mean "It kind of works sometimes, in some situations, but sometimes doesn't and we're not intending to fix it."